# Tkinter label changing does not work with any method

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having a struggle with my Python Tkinter GUI. I would like to update the text of PickedFileName to change to the fileName found in PickFileButton(). Results online indicate I can achieve this using StringVar() or .config(), but neither option seems to cooperate. Using StringVar() only renders the text as py_var0, and using .config() does not seem to recognise PickedFileName (i.e. not defined) when I run the code. I would also like to create a similar label of '[filename] generated' once ParseFileButton is pressed where [filename.log] would become [filename.txt], but this also sees similar issues. Everything else seems to function as accordingly.
I have attached a snippet of the relevant code below.

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        root.title("TF2 Log Parser")
        #setting window size
        width=500
        height=400
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        ParserTitle=tk.Message(root)
        ParserTitle["font"] = 'Bahnschrift', 24
        ParserTitle["fg"] = "#333333"
        ParserTitle["justify"] = "center"
        ParserTitle["text"] = "Parser"
        ParserTitle.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.05,width=450,height=100)

        PickedFileName=tk.Label(root)
        PickedFileName["font"] = 'Bahnschrift', 24
        PickedFileName["fg"] = "#333333"
        PickedFileName["justify"] = "center"
        PickedFileName["text"] = ""
        PickedFileName.place(x=150,y=150,width=200,height=60)

        PickFileButton=tk.Button(root)
        PickFileButton["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        PickFileButton["font"] = ft
        PickFileButton["fg"] = "#000000"
        PickFileButton["justify"] = "center"
        PickFileButton["text"] = "Select File"
        PickFileButton.place(x=150,y=200,width=200,height=46)
        PickFileButton["command"] = self.PickFileButton_command

        ParseFileButton=tk.Button(root)
        ParseFileButton["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        ParseFileButton["font"] = ft
        ParseFileButton["fg"] = "#000000"
        ParseFileButton["justify"] = "center"
        ParseFileButton["text"] = "Parse"
        ParseFileButton.place(x=170,y=330,width=160,height=38)
        ParseFileButton["command"] = self.ParseFileButton_command

    def PickFileButton_command(self):
        global filepath
        filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select Log File",
                                        filetypes =(("logs", "*.log"),("All Files", "*.*")))
        global fileName
        fileName = os.path.basename(filepath)
        global fileValidity
        print(fileName)
        if fileName.endswith('.log') == True:
            statLogs = lp.logParse(filepath)
            global gameStats
            gameStats = statLogs[0]
            global playerStats
            playerStats = statLogs[1]
            fileValidity = True
            label.config()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Invalid File", "Invalid file or no file submitted. PLease select a .log file.")
            fileValidity = False

    def ParseFileButton_command(self):
        if fileValidity == True:
            global playerStats
            playerStats = lc.statCalculations(playerStats, gameStats)
            lo.finalOutput(fileName, gameStats, playerStats)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Invalid File", "Invalid file or no file submitted. Please select a .log file before parsing.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Am I approaching this wrong? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to where in your code have you tried to change the text?

Answer (score 1):

In your init function change all of your widget instances to be class attributes by adding `self.` to the start of them. For example

```
PickedFileName=tk.Label(root)
```

becomes

```
self.PickedFileName=tk.Label(root)
```

Then, modify your `PickFileButton_command` method to change

```
label.config()
```

to

```
self.PickedFileName["text"] = fileName
```

This will update the label's text to be that of the selected file name.